# dojo web application authentication

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, dojo

I am attempting to develop a pure javascript web application using Dojo. The problem I face is one of restricting access to portions of the application. Authenticated users should be able to access everything, whereas non authenticated users should only be able to access a login screen.

The issue is that nothing (that I am aware of) will stop a user from opening up a browser javascript terminal and entering something like: `app.displayRestrictedContent();` and thus gaining access to a screen intended for authenticated users.

I have implemented an ajax based login; all ajax calls are secured with a session. So while the non-authenticated user can load a restricted screen, they wont be able to fetch data for it. But still, It seems wrong for this screen to be arbitrarily accessible.

Am I trying to do the impossible? It seems silly to write code such as `if (user.auth) app.displayRestrictedContent();` when it's so easily circumvented. And this leads me to believe I am missing something rather obvious to everybody else. I can't find much information at all on pure javascript based apps and authentication models.

Comment: BTW, the back end is implemented through cakePhp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm by no means an expert, but here are some thoughts I've made on this. I don't think you've missed anything (if so, I have too) - I think this is a pretty fundamental issue with all client applications, whether it's a compiled executable or a Javascript.

Of course, the compiled executable is not particularly hampered by it, because it's been made into machine code which is very difficult to read or decompile into anything useful. With Javascript however, the application is often served exactly as you wrote it, and so it's easy to modify and reason about.

That brings me to the first semi-solution: obfuscating your Javascript. If you use Dojo's build tool with the shrinksafe parameter, all unnecessary whitespace is removed and all identifiers are shortened, making the code quite difficult to read. I called this a semi-solution, some may say even that is giving it too much credit - I myself still think it's worth doing. After all, the shrunk code downloads faster too!

The second measure I take in my apps is to separate the different parts into "build layers". For example, in my build profile, I'll have something like

```
dependencies = {
    ..
    layers: [
        { name: "../myApp/Core.js", resourceName: "myApp.Core",
          dependencies: ["myApp.Core", "myApp.Foobar"] 
        },
        { name: "../myApp/modules/Login.js", resourceName: "myApp.modules.Login",
          dependencies: ["myApp.modules.Login", "myApp.modules.LoginUi"...],
          layerDependencies: ["../myApp/Core.js"]
        },
        { name: "../myApp/modules/Secret.js", resourceName: "myApp.modules.Secret",
          dependencies: ["myApp.modules.Secret", "myApp.modules.SecretUi"],
          layerDependencies: ["../myApp/Core.js"],
          authentication: 42
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, instead of serving the built JS files directly as static files, I let the requests go through a controller in my server-side application, which checks if the JS layer requires authentication and whether or not the user is logged in with the necessary access.

This does have certain cons. The JS files aren't cached, and if I had all my JS in one build layer, the application would probably load slightly faster. There's of course also a limit to how nuanced it's worthwhile to make the layers. More layers mean more hassle, but also more finely grained module access.

I'd be interested to hear others chime in on this as well. It's a good question.

Comment: Could you talk more about the layering and authentication system you use for getting js assets back to the browser?

Answer (score 2):

```
But still, It seems wrong for this screen to be arbitrarily accessible.
```

Because it's client-side code. Anything you write in js, or get compiled to js, expect it to be readable by the users.

```
Am I trying to do the impossible?
```

you can dynamically load js modules after the user authenticates. So at first, just load 1 login module. When the user logins, if successful, the server return a list of js modules to load, if not, return empty list. It also helps improve load time when the users come to your website.

Answer (score 1):

When a user successfully logins the server should provide him with a **session token**. The Afterwards, whenever the user requests a resource (either via just redirecting the browser or via AJAX) he shows the server his session token (either by storing it in a cookie and sending it automatically on all requests or by explicitely passing it in the body of an AJAX request)

The server can then use session tokens from the users to control authorizations server-side, rejecting any request with an invalid or outdated token.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Session_management

Comment: Thanks, I have a working knowledge of sessions. The question relates directly to the client-side nature of Javascript applications and how non authorised users may access restricted areas.

Comment: That was what I said. In the client side you get to keep a session identifier that you can use to authenticate yourself. In the server side you authorize access to resources based on the session identifiers that are presented (and this needs to be done on the server side - the client can't be trusted). (BTW, I don't see how the accepted answer has anything to do with authentication - it only talks about the dojo build system and it is *very easy* to work around compressed Javascript)

Comment: The answer provides insight into developing a javascript application using Dojo, which is what I am also doing. The answer addressed my question in a specific manner.

Comment: Thing is, the build system is completely orthogonal to building a dojo App. You first build the app normaly (and with authentication already) and only then you can use the build system to take your already-functionning app into another more optimized version.